# Problem in debugging VSIX (visual studio extension)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I'm using visual studio 2019. After installing vsix workload I simply create a new vsix project that include package.cs and hit F5 to launch debugger.
After all this work no break point is working. And let me say that my assembly is not loaded in Module explorer.
I Changed the Project attribute (Include Debug Symbol in VSIX Container) to true and nothing changed

Any help appreciated

Comment: VSPackages are loaded on demand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages?view=vs-2019 

Are you by chance missing a ProvideAutoLoad attribute on your package class?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.provideautoloadattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: No I added that attribute. I said my assembly did not loaded when I checking module view. If the problem was that at least the assembly should be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSIX project is empty and there are no components installed VS exp.

You could follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2019) to add a simple command, then you can see the assembly has been loaded by debugger.

[image]